# H264 firefox standalone on Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: firefox, video, 14.10, codecs, h264

I'm on Ubuntu 14.10.

FF 35 has support form H264 and VP8, but not MSE and VP9. That is ok, and confirmed by youtube html5 page, https://www.youtube.com/html5, as you see the screen #1 here: http://4.ii.gl/Z8rHCj-Ao.png 
FF35 is the stable version installed from official ubuntu repo.

FF 37 (dev edition), downloaded, uncompressed and launched (no ppa), has support for MSE and VP9, a new feature in FF, but H264 is gone. See screen #2 here: http://4.ii.gl/VtNFAbVCy.png

Is there a way to have FF37 "see" the H264 driver?

Thanks.

Comment: Firefox uses OpenH264 for H.264 support by default, which has a license incompatible with the rest of Firefox' source code. I suspect that the maintainers of the Firefox dev build channel(s) just don't bother with the additional hassle of shipping separate binaries for OpenH264 because the two can't be bundled together easily.